# how to plot a function subject to constraints in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, plot, constraints, inequality

I have this function:

```
function f=cost(x)
f=1.10471*x(1)^2*x(2)+0.04811*x(3)*x(4)*(14.0+x(2));
```

subject to

```
g(1)=tau-tau_max;
g(2)=sigma-sigma_max;
g(3)=x(1)-x(4);
g(4)=0.10471*x(1)^2+0.04811*x(3)*x(4)*(14+x(2))-5.0;
g(5)=0.125-x(1);
g(6)=delta-delta_max;
g(7)=P-PcX;
```

all g[1..7] should be <= 0

I have to keep any two of them as a constant and plot the f(x)
The upper and lower bounds are respectively (x1..x4)

```
LowerBound=[0.125  0.1   0.1  0.125];
UpperBound=[5.0   10.0  10.0    5.0];
```

thanks in advance...

edit: so  far what i have done:

```
function [x1,x2,x3,x4]=objFuncPlot
[x2, x3] = meshgrid(0.1:.1:10, 0.1:.1:10);
//x1 and x4 is constant
x1=0.1996;
x4=0.2107;
//calculating constraints
[g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7]=constraints(x1,x2,x3,x4); 
G1=[g1,g2,g4,g6,g7];
G2=[g3,g5];
infeasible=~all(G1(:)<=0) | ~all(G2(:)<=0);
//objective function
f=1.10471.*x1^2.*x2+0.04811.*x3.*x4.*(14.0+x2);
f(infeasible)=nan;
//plotting surf
surf(x2,x3,f,'LineStyle','none');
view(68,20)
hold on
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z');
hold off

//Constraints & Constants & Equations
function [g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7]=constraints(x1,x2,x3,x4)
P=6000;
L=14;
E=30.*10^6;
G=12.*10^6;
tau_max=13600;
sigma_max=30000;
delta_max=0.25;
M=P*(14+x2./2);
R=sqrt(x2^2./4+(x1+x3)^2./4);
J=2.*(x1.*x2.*sqrt(2).*(x2^2/12+(x1+x3)^2/4));
tau_one=P./(sqrt(2).*x1.*x2);
tau_two=(M.*R)./J;
tau=sqrt(tau_one^2+2.*tau_one.*tau_two.*x2./(2.*R)+tau_two^2);
sigma=(6.*P.*L)./(x4.*x3^2);
delta=(4.*P.*L^3)./(30.*10^6.*x4.*x3^3);
PcX=4.013.*E./L^2.*sqrt(x3^2.*x4^6./36).*(1-x3.*sqrt(E./(4.*G))./(2.*L));
g1=tau-tau_max;
g2=sigma-sigma_max;
g3=x1-x4;
g4=0.10471.*x1^2+0.04811.*x3.*x4.*(14+x2)-5.0;
g5=0.125-x1;
g6=delta-delta_max;
g7=P-PcX;
```

Comment: Assuming the constraints are the problem: You can take the function on the full domain, and then make all function values where the constraints are not met into NaN. I guess you can do this one constraint at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to define a new function which returns 1 when its argument is less than or equal to zero and returns NaN for +ve arguemnt

```
function H = mod_neg_step(argument)
         H = zeros(size(argument));
         H(argument<= 0) = 1;
         H(argument> 0) = NaN;
end
```

Then redefine your function f as

```
f=1.10471*x(1)^2*x(2)+0.04811*x(3)*x(4)*(14.0+x(2));
f=f*mod_neg_step(g(1))*mod_neg_step(g(2))*mod_neg_step(g(3))*mod_neg_step(g(4))...
  *mod_neg_step(g(5))*mod_neg_step(g(6))*mod_neg_step(g(7));
```

This will ensure that when g(1)...g(7) are positive your function f returns value NaN.Only when all of g(1)...g(7) are 0 or negative, function f will return

```
f=1.10471*x(1)^2*x(2)+0.04811*x(3)*x(4)*(14.0+x(2));
```

Comment: thanks but this is like a penalty function. i can apply penalty function already. what i need is something like a pseucode to plot objective function while two dimensions are constant. can u help me about that please?

Comment: sure. Just give me the expressions/values for tau, tau_max, delta, delta_max,P,PcX

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29725-accelerated-particle-swarm-optimization/content/apso_weld.m here is the full problem and a solution with PSO algorithm. this gave me the fmin and gbest. but what i need is plotting the objective function. thanks in advance

Comment: i added what i have done so far into the first post. could you please check it for me? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have a function of FOUR independent variables, so essentially a FIVE dimensional thing. What do you want to plot????????? You have a monitor, or a piece of paper. These things have two dimensions, not five.

The constraints here are not that important because you cannot plot this relationship anyway.

Just wanting to do something is not enough for it to happen. If wishes were horses, beggars would ride.

Comment: I am just trying to determine the feasible region for the function. here is a sample but i didnt understand exactly. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/274035

Comment: @egazi - sorry, but you are not reading what I said, not thinking about the problem. This domain is a 4 dimensional domain in the parameters. How will you plot it? The example you show was in fewer number of dimensions. I don't care that you WANT to do something. Wanting something is not enough to make it possible.

Comment: mate i explained in my first post, i dont know how to say corretly but i will make two of them constant and plot rest. for example: x1=2 x2=4 then plot for x3 and x4. i think we can do that, right?

Comment: @egazi - this will require you to find a polygonal region in the two remaining parameters. In theory, contour can do it, if you carefully establish an objective.

Comment: i added what i have done so far into the first post. could you please check it for me? thanks a lot